# MySQL storing accented characters as '?' - MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am using PHP to upload a CSV file that contains french accents to the DB and the accents are being stored as '?'.

I have set the following character to send when connecting to the database:

`$dbConn->exec("set names utf8mb4");`

The Collation for database and the columns are set to "utf8mb4_general_ci".

Are there any extra steps to do for MariaDB? Note: The same thing is working fine on a MySQL server.

Comment: Is the file actually UTF8, or is it something else like ISO8859-1 or cp1252?

Comment: No, the file is 'iso8859-15'.

Comment: Then you need to convert the data from that to UTF8 using [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding).

Comment: Or use `SET NAMES latin9` instead of `SET NAMES utf8`? (Latin9 being the equivalent of ISO-8859-15)

Comment: @Sammitch yes, this is what I ended up doing.